# pass id of the selected checkbox(which areloaded with ngFor) when it is checked

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, ngfor

```
       <form name="check-boxes">
          <div *ngFor="let quest of noOfQuestions">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let ans of noOfAnswers">
              <label class="form-check-label">{{ans}}
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="{{quest}}" id="{{quest}}{{type}}" value="{{ans}}"  (change)="getAnswers(id)"> 
              <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Sample Output in angular componentx.html:
[image]

This code generates a set of checkbox according to noOfQuestions and noOfAnswers provided. I want to pass the particular id of the checkbox to the function 'getAnswer' when a checkbox is checked. Passed parameter 'id' value in ts file, is said undefined. What should be the parameter to getAnswer() to pass the seleced checkbox's id???

Comment: Does the object `quest` have any variables? What type is it? maybe you could do `(change)="getAnswers(quest.id)"`

Comment: quest is just a number

Comment: ```id="{{quest}}{{type}}"``` this is your id right?

Comment: yes its the id of radio button

Comment: @AnupamaThathsarani You can use this approach too. [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59669899/12609535)

Answer (score 3):

if you pass the $event:

```
(change)="getAnswers($event)"
```

then you should have access to that input element in your typescript file through `event.target` but it's also important that you check whether is checked or not:

```
getAnswers(event) {
   if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log('checked: ' + event.target.id);
   } else {
      console.log('unchecked: ' + event.target.id);
   }
}
```

Comment: When using $event as parameter, It works fine Thank You

Comment: I know, I'm also learning angular now :) It would be great if you mark the answer as correct if you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

In your html

```
(change)="getAnswers(quest,type)"
```

In your typescript

```
//I have no idea about the types of parameters you used.
getAnswers(quest: any, type: any) 
{
    console.log('Id: ' + `${quest}${type}`);
}
```